# Django logs not displaying in docker container with Gunicorn when DEBUG = False

Tags: django, docker, gunicorn

I have a Django application that I'm trying to containerize for Kubernetes, I don't need nginx, I have Kubernetes load balancer. I have created a Docker file for the Django container as follows:

```
FROM python:3.11-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN apk add musl-dev mariadb-dev gcc
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY . .

RUN python manage.py collectstatic

CMD ["gunicorn"  , "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000", "app.wsgi"]
```

I have set DEBUG = False in my Django settings, and I would like to see the Django logs in the container. However, when I run the container, I only see the following logs:

```
datetime [datetime] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
datetime [datetime] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:80 (1)
datetime [datetime] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
datetime [datetime] [1] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
```

I have tried to set up the default logging configuration in my Django settings as follows:

```
LOGGING = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": False,
    "handlers": {
        "console": {
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
        },
    },
    "root": {
        "handlers": ["console"],
        "level": "INFO",
    },
}
```

However, I still don't see any Django logs in the container. Is there anything else I need to configure to get the Django logs to display when running the container (visited site, errors etc..)?

Thank you!

Comment: You mentioned "DEBUG = False".  Does it behave differently with "DEBUG = True"?  What log messages are present in your code?  If you're not logging, you won't get any output.

Comment: It looks like you might be missing components of your logging config, since your LOGGING doesn't explicitly declare a file / stream path: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#custom-handling-of-levels (but I'm not familiar with Gunicorn, so maybe the default works?)
Also, you may need to use a SocketHandler instead of a StreamHandler: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#deploying-web-applications-using-gunicorn-and-uwsgi. Also try setting the "level" to "DEBUG" while you try to find the issue.

Comment: what is the advantages of SocketHandler instead of StreamHandler here?
Btw I've answered the question in the below comment...

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it using this logging:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    'root': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'level': 'INFO',
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': False,
        },
    },
}
```

as well as in Dockerfile:

`CMD ["gunicorn"  , "--bind", "0.0.0.0:80", "--access-logfile" ,"-" ,"my_app.wsgi"]`

I hope I helped